# Chrome Dev Tools - Performance tab missing JS trace

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am using Chrome to debug an app. Usualy I get a complete stacktrace when profiling my app.

But recently the stack just disappeared. It only shows the layering, drawing and native events, but no longer the JavaScript executions.

In the settings I have uncheckt the "Disable JavaScript samples" and tested all other preferences regarding the performance tab. Nothing helped.

Other sites (like stackoverflow) won't work eighther. Chromium has the same problem.
I am running this on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

Anyone else has a clue how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm affected by this as well. I filed an issue at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1071961. Perhaps you could add more detail so the Chrome team can fix it faster.

Are you using an Intel CPU or an AMD one? I'm using one of the latest AMD Threadrippers. Wondering if that may be the cause.

Comment: I checked that this is fixed in Chromium 84. It is slated to roll into stable Chrome in July 2020.